# unable to set autoscale in cosmos db using terraform

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to add autoscale settings to cosmos db but its not allowing the shard_key value as null. because right now we dont have shard_key but still want to utlitze the auto scale feature. I can see in azure portal that is allowed when I import the resources created without shard_key in the portal the value is showing null, but while creation I am not able to do it.

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_mongo_collection" "collections" {

  name                = "dbCollName"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_cosmosdb_account.cosmosdb.resource_group_name
  account_name        = local.account_name
  database_name       = "dbName"
  shard_key           = null

  autoscale_settings = {
          max_throughput = 4000
  }
 
}
```

Comment: You can only create a fixed sized collection without the shard key. If you plan on needing to scale this collection, you will need to decide on a shard key before creating it because you cannot change this once it's been created.

Comment: Azure portal and ARM template allows autoscale for unsharded collections upto 10K RU's. While I understand the importance of shard key rightnow we don't have it in the app

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my environment ,setting up autoscale setting without shard key is not possible using terraform.

> **Error:**
>
> [image]

> When I add some value in Shard_key , it gets success.
>
> [image]

**From Terraform Documentation:**

> autoscale_settings - (Optional) An autoscale_settings block as defined
> below. This must be set upon database creation otherwise it cannot be
> updated without a manual terraform destroy-apply. Requires shard_key
> to be set.

As per the above its mandatory to set the Shard_key value for adding the autoscale settings using terraform.

For alternate solution , you have to use ARM_template/Bicep/Portal. You can refer the below link for templates on the same.

**Reference:**

[Azure-QuickStart-Templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.documentdb/cosmosdb-mongodb-autoscale)